# How make responsive background on div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, background, responsive-images

I am trying to make responsive background images on a `div` element but it does not work.

Here is my CSS:

```css
.block-main{
  background: url(images/ohdaihiep/bg1.png) center center/cover no-repeat;
  min-height:863px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail of your problem and the markup too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vh` and `vw` to make it responsive:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/djxy7eup/1/) to play around.

```css
.block-main {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/301/301)center center/cover no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-main">

</div>
```